# Remove unwanted JavaScript from WooCommerce product page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm just researching the way to remove unwanted JavaScript from the Woocommerce `products` and `product category` pages.

Wordpress has a plugin, [Plugin Organizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/), to remove scripts from the WP pages but it doesn't handle Woocommerece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a answer for this. Actually in the same plugin it has option to enable it for Woocommerce. GO to Settings->Plugin Organizer in the admin menu and enable that post type in the custom post type box.That's all